# Compare input string with multiple keys in Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public class Test {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, City> cities = new HashMap<>();
        cities.put("Rome", new City("Rome", "Italy", 2869461));
        cities.put("Berlin", new City("Berlin", "Germany", 3610156));
        cities.put("Lisbon", new City("Lisbon", "Portugal", 545245));
        Iterator<String> keySetIterator = cities.keySet().iterator();
        System.out.println("HashMap has " + cities.size() + " elements");
        System.out.print("Enter a city to search for ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String searchtext = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println(searchtext);
        System.out.println("Key result " + cities.containsKey(searchtext));

        String key = keySetIterator.next();
            System.out.println("key: " + key + " value: " + cities.get(key).getName());
            if (cities.get(key).getName().contains(searchtext)) {
                      System.out.println("Value result found " + cities.get(key).getCountry() + " " + cities.get(key).getPopulation());
            }
```

I have this code in main and I have one class (City) that has only getter,setters and constructor.
When i run the code,it running complete only when

> searchtext = Rome

...If I put

> Lisbon

the code doesn't insert in the last "if" and I dont know why.Any help?

Comment: You're only comparing against the very first entry.

Comment: `keySetIterator.next()` is just gonna return one entry from the iterator and you are comparing the input against it, which is causing the issue. Instead you could just search the input against the keys in the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asimac,

It looks like you're only getting the first key with

```
String key = keySetIterator.next();
```

I think you'll want to check all of the entries instead of just the first.

Consider something like this:

```
while(keySetIterator.hasNext()){
        String key = keySetIterator.next();
        System.out.println("key: " + key + " value: " + cities.get(key).getName());
        if (cities.get(key).getName().contains(searchtext)) {
                  System.out.println("Value result found " + cities.get(key).getCountry() + " " + cities.get(key).getPopulation());
        }
}
```

Comment: Note to the OP: the flaw in your design is that more than one value in the map might have the search term as a substring of its name.  Consider a map that has the cities "New York", "New London", "New Brunswick", and "New Orleans", with the search term "New ". What should the iterator algorithm return?